# Swift 2: How to Load UITabBarController after Showing LoginViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift2

Am new to Swift and Storyboard. At initially I have to show the login page and from the login page to UITabBarController. Once the user remembered the login details I have to check the login details in the AppDelegate and show the UITabBarController directly if the user already logged in. I have referred some SOF questions but, am not getting the result.

> I designed the LoginViewController embedded with
>   UINavigationController. And I have one UITabBarController with 2
>   viewcontrollers. I set the LoginViewController as a
>   inititialViewController in Storyboard. So the loginview is showing at
>   very first time. But, I don't know how to push the UITabBarController
>   from the login screen (Login Button Action). Also I don't know how to
>   check and load the login and tabbar

respectively from appDelegate.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction (button : UIButton) {

        if isRemeberLogin == true {
            let loginClass = LoginModelClass(userNameValue: (usernameTF?.text)!, passwordValue: (passwordTF?.text)!)
            print("Remembering Login Details: \(loginClass.userName, loginClass.passWord)")

        }

        let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        let collectionVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemsCollectionViewController") as! ItemsCollectionViewController


        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true)

        let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController

        print("TABBAR \(tabBarController)")
        let viewControllersArray = [homeVC, collectionVC];
       // tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewControllersArray

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarController, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: Please follow this link, there is working solution. What you should NOT do is what Abhishek Sharma said, even though it is easier solution, it might hurt you in the long run. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514195/segueing-to-another-view-controller-without-displaying-the-first-in-ios-8/31515899#31515899

Comment: @JiriTrecak Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. I resolved the issue and here is my code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch

        let username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username")
        print(username)

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

        if username?.length > 0 {
            print("User already logged In")
            let tabBarController: UITabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        } else {
            print("New User")
            let loginViewController: ViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
        }


        return true
    }
```

This is from Login Button Action:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let tabBarController: UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Just mention the "TabBarController" as Identity in Storyboard for the UITabBarController. I have created a Viewcontroller embedded with UINavigationController and UITabBarController with three UIViewControllers separately.

I hope it will help someone else. Thanks.

Comment: Very good solution :) minor improvement to be made: next time just make it new method so you don't clog the application delegate :)

Comment: Ya sure. I will keep these set of code in a method. Thank you :)

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M hi do I need to add something special in appdelegate class?

Comment: @VAAA Hi. Nothing to be added except these check. It is based on your project functionalities. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in `image` your storyboard must be look like following.
[image]

Then give `Storyboard Segue` identifier which navigate you to `UITabbarController` from `LoginViewController`.

Then `paste` following code from where you want to navigate.

```
@IBAction func btnLogin_Click(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginToTabBar", sender: self)
    //LoginToTabBar is identifier which you settled out in storyboard segue.

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)