# Update UITabBarController bar item from NSObject class

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have NSObject class listening for a specific event from my server.

When this specific event happens, I would like to update the badge value of an existing tabBar item from my UITabBarController called TabBarController.

How can I access it from the NSObject class?

Below is the NSOBject class listening for the event.

The function connectedToSocketIo() is launched when the application is launched.

The print("Event is working") is displayed in the terminal so everything is working.

The only thing I need now is to be able to update the badge of a specific bar item.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON


class SocketIOManager: NSObject{

    func connectedToSocketIo(){

        socket.on("post-channel:App\\Events\\contact\\newContactRequest"){ (data, ack) -> Void in

            let json = JSON(data)

            if json[0]["id"].string! == self.defaults.stringForKey("user_id")! {

                print("event is working")
                // I want to change the tab bar item badge here

            } else {

                print("no event")

            }
        } 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you starting the socket in AppDelegate?

Comment: @ryantxr yes. under: applicationDidBecomeActive through a function in my socketManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I found another way which avoid touching my socket.io instance.

Source:

[Swift 2: How to Load UITabBarController after Showing LoginViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562015/swift-2-how-to-load-uitabbarcontroller-after-showing-loginviewcontroller)

I just make the link with my tab bar controller as follow:

- In my SocketIOManager

  ```
  //"MainTabBarController" being the UITabBarController identifier I have set in the storyboard.
  //TabBarController being my custom UITabBarController class. 
  // receivedNotification() being a method defined in my custom TabBarController class

  let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)            

  let tabBarController: TabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBarController") as! TabBarController

  tabBarController.receivedNotification(1)
  ```
- In my TabBarController class:

  ```
  func receivedNotification(barItem: Int){

      if let actualValue = self.tabBar.items![barItem].badgeValue {

          let currentValue = Int(actualValue)

          self.tabBar.items![barItem].badgeValue = String(currentValue! + 1)

      } else {

          self.tabBar.items![barItem].badgeValue = "1"

      }

      // Reload tab bar item
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

      appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = self
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get a reference to the `UITabBarController` in your `SocketIOManager` class. Once you have a reference the tab bar controller you can change the badge value of the desired `UITabBarItem`.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    /*
        var tabBarController: UITabBarController!
    */

    // When the tabBarController gets set the connectedToSocketIO function gets automatically called.
    var tabBarController: UITabBarController! {
        didSet {
            connectedToSocketIO()
        }
    }

    init() {
        super.init()
    }

    // Either call this function
    init(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {
        super.init()

        self.tabBarController = tabBarController
        connectedToSocketIO()
    }

    // Or create a setter
    func setTabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {
        self.tabBarController = tabBarController
    }


    func connectedToSocketIo() {

        socket.on("post-channel:App\\Events\\contact\\newContactRequest"){ (data, ack) -> Void in

            let json = JSON(data)

            if json[0]["id"].string! == self.defaults.stringForKey("user_id")! {

                print("event is working")

                // Set the desired tab bar item to a given value
                tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0].badgeValue = "1"

            } else {

                print("no event")

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```swift
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var socketIOManager: SocketIOManager!

    viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        socketIOManager = SocketIOManager(tabBarController: self)
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get the following error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. Seems that the SocketIOManager cannot find my tabBarController...

Comment: You should call `connectedToSocketIo()` only when your `UITabBarController` has been loaded. I have edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: I have added 'SocketIOManager(tabBarController: self)' to my custom tabBarController in the viewDidLoad. I have a warning mentioning the result is unused. And the error remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the `socketIOManager` property in the `CustomTabBarController`. Also in the `init()` function of the `SocketIOManager` you should call `super.init()`.

Comment: After making the adjustment, the socketIOManager is not listening anymore. I even don't get the print("event is working") anymore

Comment: Could you please post the code that interacts with the SocketIOManager?

Comment: Just posted the detail below. Let me know if not clear enough

Comment: So I have looked at your code. It is normal that the `print("event is working")` doesn't get called. When you call `establishConnection()` in the app delegate a singleton is created with the `init()` function. Therefore the `init(UITabBarController)` never gets called (there is already an instance of your `SocketIOManager`). Either call the `establishConnection()` from the `CustomTabBarController` or create a setter that you call in the `CustomTabBarController` and call the `connectedToSocketIO()` function afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

@Jessy Naus

I removed:

- the socket connection from the app delegate,
- the override init function inside the socketIOManager so the init(UITabBarController)

and added the socket.connect() (from socket.io library) function inside the init function linked to the tab bar controller as follow:

```
init(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {

    super.init()

    self.tabBarController = tabBarController

    socket.connect()

    self.listeningToSocketEvent()
}
```

I have replaced "self.connectedToSocketIo()" by "listeningToSocketEvent()" has the meaning of this function is more clear.

All together following your instructions mentioned above = Works perfectly. So I put your answer as the good one.

Really not easy concept. Will still need some time to assimilate it and apply it to other components of the UI.

Thanks a lot for your help on this!